# tastypie custom fields

Tags: django, tastypie

User and UserProfile is related with 'OneToOneField'

I have fields = [] to suppress all other fields listed in the dehydrate method,
but it doesn't work.(shows all the fields in the UserProfile model)

```
class UserProfileResource(ModelResource):

    user = fields.OneToOneField(UserResource, 'user')

    class Meta:
        queryset = UserProfile.objects.all()
        fields = [] ## here, this doesn't work as intended

    def dehydrate(self, bundle):
        bundle.data['username'] = bundle.obj.user.username
        bundle.data['id'] = bundle.obj.user.id
        bundle.data['url_profile_image'] = bundle.obj.url_profile_image # this is a property call
        bundle.data['url_profile_image_thumbnail'] = bundle.obj.url_profile_image_thumbnail
        return bundle
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it's a strange behavior of Tastypie. But `fields = ['']` works as well.